# Why I am getting error in Angular. can't GET /

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-errorhandler

I was facing the error **can't GET /** in Angular after implementing the Route.

Comment: please be very specific about the error and make sure you share the code for us to understand your problem and hep you resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In app-route.module.ts , Don't give space in Home directory.
For Example :: { path: '', component: AngularComponent },

in navbar.component.html , do as give below

Home